# Apex Serverless: How to configure Scheduled Events/S3 triggers with Apex

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, apex

I think it might be very basic question ( might be not ). I want to use Apex for my lambda functions since I need just lambdas not API gateways so i don't want use bulky Serverless.

But just creating lambdas won't help I need to schedule some event and triggers.

Can someone out there help me with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apex uses Terraform to build AWS infastructure. They support building cloud watch event rules which are used to trigger Lambda on cron.

Here are the documents from Terraform. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_event_rule.html

This is the link to the S3 Bucket notification which allow you to setup triggers to Lambda.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_event_rule.html